# Syntax error while creating table as a join of two tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create new table by joining two tables, using the following query on a MySQL DBMS:

```
create table t11 as 
SELECT * FROM banking
JOIN details ON details.[account number]= banking.[account number]
```

which is firing a syntax error. Where is the mistake in it?

Answer (score 0):

Delimiting field and table names with brackets is SQL-Server notation. In MySQL you may want to use backticks instead.

```
CREATE TABLE t11 AS 
SELECT * 
FROM banking 
JOIN details ON details.`account number` = banking.`account number`
```

Or avoid using them completely, if:

- they're composed by one word
- there's no correspondence with any [MySQL reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).